# Creating monsters with a for loop generating id's

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine

I am new to game programming and C#, but I have some programming experience from javaScript and PHP.

OK here we go, I have a C# script that i want to use for monster generation. I have followed Tom Adamson on Youtube up to the point where he starts generating random values seen here: [UNITY3D C# with Tom Adamson](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLkHEpMJMGc)

Here is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class myMonster : MonoBehaviour {

    public class aMonster {

        //The properties
        public int id;
        public int age;
        public string name;
        public string race;
        public int health;

        //A method
        public void monsterData() {
            print("ID: "        + id);
            print("Race: "      + race);
            print("Name: "      + name);
            print("Age: "       + age);
            print("Health: "    + health);
        }

    } // End of class definition

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    void Start () {

        aMonster[] bigMonster = new aMonster[51];

        for (int i = 1; i <= 50;) {

            bigMonster[i] = new aMonster();
            bigMonster[i].id = i;
            bigMonster[i].name = "Gorky";
            bigMonster[i].race = "Orc";
            bigMonster[i].age = 320;
            bigMonster[i].health = 200;
            i++;

            bigMonster[i] = new aMonster();
            bigMonster[i].id = i;
            bigMonster[i].name = "Runathu";
            bigMonster[i].race = "Shaman";
            bigMonster[i].age = 670;
            bigMonster[i].health = 100;
            i++;

        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            bigMonster[i].monsterData();
        }

    }

}
```

When i have only 2 monsters this works fine, but when i try to add a third monster i get this error:

IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
(wrapper stelemref) object:stelemref (object,intptr,object)
myMonster.Start () (at Assets/myMonster.cs:50)

I have added the third monster like this:

```
bigMonster[i] = new aMonster();
            bigMonster[i].id = i;
            bigMonster[i].name = "Gorky";
            bigMonster[i].race = "Orc";
            bigMonster[i].age = 320;
            bigMonster[i].health = 200;
            i++;

            bigMonster[i] = new aMonster();
            bigMonster[i].id = i;
            bigMonster[i].name = "Runathu";
            bigMonster[i].race = "Shaman";
            bigMonster[i].age = 670;
            bigMonster[i].health = 100;
            i++;

            bigMonster[i] = new aMonster();
            bigMonster[i].id = i;
            bigMonster[i].name = "Tiny";
            bigMonster[i].race = "Spider";
            bigMonster[i].age = 90;
            bigMonster[i].health = 45;
            i++;
```

Could anyone tell me what i am doing wrong? i guess that i++ is the wrong way of doing this since the third monster is causing the error.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You are using the for loop incorrectly. You should add one monster per loop and each loop i is incremented. `for (int i = 1; i <= 50;) ` should be `for (int i = 0; i < 51; i++) `

Comment: keeping it i <= 50 is still ok but the problem is int i should equal 0 not 1.

Comment: @Tobberoth: The usage here is a bit odd, but not incorrect in itself.  Any of the three parts in the parens can be omitted, as long as the semicolons are still there to mark where the parts start/end.  And good luck adding one monster per iteration when there are three different types.  By the time you've gotten around to doing that in an acceptable fashion, you may as well have done what's being done here.

Comment: @cHao: That's true. I guess the very basic concept is just... weird. Why would one add individual monsters several times to an array, it makes no sense. Either create the monsters individually and add to an array, or use a for loop to add a monster many times.

Comment: It makes sense enough, if you think about the intent.  If you want an even distribution of monsters, you could pre-do the math to figure out how many of each you want, and add each monster X times, or you could simply keep adding a set of them til you have enough.  Either will work, but the latter requires less prep work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
aMonster[] bigMonster = new aMonster[51];
```

means you have 51 monsters (max index=50) but you are incrementing i twice in one for loop which at last iteration has i=50, so you are trying to reach `aMonster[51]`

FIX:

start your loop from i=0 and end at i=49, indexes in c# are **starting from 0 not 1**

also I suggest you to transform your code to:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i+=2) 
    {

        bigMonster[i] = new aMonster();
        bigMonster[i].id = i;
        bigMonster[i].name = "Gorky";
        bigMonster[i].race = "Orc";
        bigMonster[i].age = 320;
        bigMonster[i].health = 200;


        bigMonster[i+1] = new aMonster();
        bigMonster[i+1].id = i;
        bigMonster[i+1].name = "Runathu";
        bigMonster[i+1].race = "Shaman";
        bigMonster[i+1].age = 670;
        bigMonster[i+1].health = 100;

    }
```

incrementing in for loop should be done in definition of for loop, it looks cleaner.

EDIT:

most elegant and safe solution, use `List<aMonster>()`

```
var bigMonster = new List<aMonster>();
var id = 0;
for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
{
    bigMonster.Add(new aMonster { id=id++,name="Gorky",race="Orc",age=320,health=200 });
    bigMonster.Add(new aMonster { id=id++,name="Runathu",race="Shaman",age=320,health=200 });
    //and so on
}
```

it will create 30 monsters of each kind, of course you can change this number by modyfing for loop

Comment: Thanks for helping me getting started, i am now starting at 0 and ending at 49, but how would i proceed at adding monsters? I 'm having problems understanding how i would use the for loop correct.

Here is what i do now, and it shows the same error:

Comment: `void Start () {

  aMonster[] bigMonster = new aMonster[50];

  for (int i = 0; i <= 49; i++) {

   bigMonster[i] = new aMonster();
   bigMonster[i].id = i;
   bigMonster[i].name = "Gorky";
   bigMonster[i].race = "Orc";
   bigMonster[i].age = 320;
   bigMonster[i].health = 200;
   i++;

....

  }

  for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   bigMonster[i].monsterData();
  }

 }`

Comment: @Dan-LeviTømta now you are incrementing one more time in your for loop, so situation is the same. First of all you can use lists and avoid indexoutofrange. I suggest you new solution in my code

Comment: don't change this aMonster[] bigMonster = new aMonster[50]; It still needs to be 51

Comment: Thanks yet again @wedzik i really appreciate you helping me. I tried copy paste the code and now i get new errors. 

Assets/myMonster.cs(30,38): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `List`1' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Assets/myMonster.cs(34,16): error CS1061: Type `object' does not contain a definition for `Add' and no extension method `Add' of type `object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

im missing something obviously, do you know what i need?

Comment: @Dan-LeviTømta at the top of your class add `using  System.Collections.Generic`

Comment: Thank you so much, now i understand :)

This is what i ended up with:

`var bigMonster = new List<aMonster>();
  var id = 0;

  for(int i=0; i<30; i++) {
      bigMonster.Add(new aMonster { id=id++,name="Gorky",race="Orc",age=320,health=200 });
      bigMonster.Add(new aMonster { id=id++,name="Runathu",race="Shaman",age=560,health=100 });
      bigMonster.Add(new aMonster { id=id++,name="Tiny",race="Spider",age=45,health=90 });
  }

  foreach(aMonster a in bigMonster) {
    a.monsterData();
  }`

Answer (score 0):

start iterating from 0

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 50;)
```

Answer (score 0):

for making things easier i would work with List instead of array. Notation would be easier as well, for example:

```
var bigMonster = new list<aMonster>();

for(int i = 1; i <=50; )
{
  var mon1 = new aMonster{id = i, name = "Gorky", race = "orc", age = 320, health = 200};
        i++;
  var mon2 = new aMonster{id = i, name = "Runathu", race = "Shaman", age = 670, health = 100};
        i++;
  var mon3 = new aMonster{id = i, name = "Tiny", race = "Spider", age = 90, health = 45};
        i++;
  bigMonster.Add(mon1);
  bigMonster.Add(mon2);
  bigMonster.Add(mon3);
}

foreach(aMonster a in bigMonster)
{
  a.monsterData();
}
```